# PHP echoing JQuery on failed form submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm working on a signup form in PHP. The form is a div which opens when you click on a button. Here's my code:

```
 if(!$fieldsFilled){  
 $unfilledFormsError = '<br><font class="text-error" id="unfilled-forms-error">One of more of the fields are empty.</font><br>';
                echo "
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#home-sign-up-box').show();
                    console.log('test passed');
                });
                </script>";
}
```

This all executes after my form is submitted:

```
    if (isset($_POST['signUp']))
```

Full PHP code:

```
    <?php require 'dbconnect.php'; ?>
<?php
    //Error message variable declarations
    $unmatchedPasswordsError = "";
    $unfilledFormsError = "";
    $emailError = "";

    //If sign up submit POST recieved
    if (isset($_POST['signUp'])) 
    {
        //Start session
        session_start();

        $email = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['suEmail']);
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");

        if ($result->num_rows) 
        {
            $emailInUse = true;
        } 
        else
        {
            $emailInUse = false;
        }

        //Search for empty fields
        $required = array('suFirstName', 'suLastName', 'suEmail', 'suPassword', 'suVerifyPassword', 'suDisplayName');
        $fieldsFilled = true;

        foreach($required as $field) 
        {
            if (empty($_POST[$field])) 
            {
                $fieldsFilled = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                $fieldsFilled = true;
            }
        }

        if ($emailInUse)
        {
            $emailError = "The email is already in use.";
            echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
               $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#home-sign-up-box').show();
                });
            </script>";
        }
        else
        {   
            if(!$fieldsFilled)
            {   
                $unfilledFormsError = '<br><font class="text-error" id="unfilled-forms-error">One of more of the fields are empty.</font><br>';
                echo "
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#home-sign-up-box').show();
                    console.log('test passed');
                });
                </script>";
            }
            else
            {
                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                {
                    $emailError = "The email is not valid.";
                    echo "
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#home-sign-up-box').show();
                    });
                    </script>";
                }
                else 
                {
                    //Check for unverified password
                    if ($_POST['suPassword']!= $_POST['suConfirmPassword'])
                    {
                        $unmatchedPasswordsError = "The passwords do not match.";
                        echo "
                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('#home-sign-up-box').show();
                        });
                        </script>";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        //Variable declaration for sign up POST values
                        $suFirstName = $_POST['suFirstName'];
                        $suLastName = $_POST['suLastName'];
                        $suEmail = $_POST['suEmail'];
                        $suPassword = $_POST['suPassword'];
                        $suDisplayName = $_POST['suDisplayName'];

                        //Insert POST values into database
                        $sql = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,email,password,displayName)Values('{$suFirstName}','{$suLastName}','{$suEmail}','{$suPassword}','{$suDisplayName}')");

                        //Redirect to 'email sent' webpage
                        header('Location: emailSent.php');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //If log in submit POST recieved
    if (isset($_POST['logIn']))
    {
        //Variable declaration for log in POST values
        $liEmail = $_POST['liEmail'];
        $liPassword = $_POST['liPassword'];

        //Search for log in credentials in dabase
        $result = $connection->query("select * from users where email = '$liEmail' AND password = '$liPassword'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);

        //TODO: CHECK FOR REMEMBER ME CHECK
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['userID'];
    }?>
```

HTML sign up div/form code:

```
    <!-- Sign Up Box -->
        <div class="sign-up-box" id="home-sign-up-box">
            <img src="images/icons/x-close.png" class="x-close" id="home-sign-up-close" src="x-close">
            <font class="subheader-bold font-raleway" id="box-sign-up-text">Sign Up</font>
            <form method="post" action="" id="home-sign-up-form">
                <input type="text" name="suFirstName" placeholder="First Name" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-first-name-text-input" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['suFirstName'])){echo $_POST['suFirstName'];}?>">
                <input type="text" name="suLastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-last-name-text-input" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['suLastName'])){echo $_POST['suLastName'];}?>">
                <input type="text" name="suEmail" placeholder="Email" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-email-text-input"value="<?php if(isset($_POST['suEmail'])){echo $_POST['suEmail'];}?>">
                <?php 
                    echo '<br><font class="text-error" id="email-error">',$emailError,'</font>'; 
                ?>
                <input type="password" name="suPassword" placeholder="Password" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-password-text-input">
                <input type="password" name="suConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-confirm-password-text-input">
                <?php 
                    echo '<br><font class="text-error" id="passwords-unmatched-error">',$unmatchedPasswordsError,'</font>'; 
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="suDisplayName" placeholder="Display Name (you can change this later)" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-display-name-text-input" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['suDisplayName'])){echo $_POST['suDisplayName'];}?>">
                <?php 
                    echo $unfilledFormsError; 
                ?>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="suRememberMe" value="yes" id="sign-up-remember-me-checkbox"><font id="sign-up-remember-me-text">Remember me</font></label>
                <input name="signUp" type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="sign-up-submit">
            </form>
            <font class="text-minor" id="agree-tos-pp-text">By signing up, you agree to our <a href="#">terms of service</a> and <br><a href="#">privacy policy</a>.</font>
        </div>
```

The "test passed" does log to the console, however the div is not showing after the page refresh (due to form submission). Any help is appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried using Ajax/XHR to run the request? You can make the request using a FormData object to send the form, and then echo whatever message you want to return using JSON, and then you can parse it on JS. This way you don't have to even leave the page to run the request. You can stop a page from refreshing or changing after submitting by doing `$("form").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); })`

Answer (score 0):

> I have customized as your requirement and database connection i have used
>   `Mysqli` replace whatever you want also change database credentials.

**Full code will be in same page. Try and comment if you don't understand anything.**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   //require 'dbconnect.php'; 
   $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test"); // I have use it for testing

    $errors = array();
    if (isset($_POST['signUp'])) {
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['suEmail']);
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");

        //email check
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $errors[] = "The email is already in use.";
        }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $errors[] = "The email is not valid.";
        }

        //Search for empty fields
        $required = array('suFirstName', 'suLastName', 'suEmail', 'suPassword', 'suConfirmPassword', 'suDisplayName');
        foreach($required as $field){
            if (empty($_POST[$field])){
                $errors[] = $field." Cannot be empty.";
            }
        }

        if(count($errors)==0){
            if($_POST['suPassword']!=$_POST['suConfirmPassword']){
                $errors[] = "The passwords do not match.";
            }else{
                $suFirstName = $_POST['suFirstName'];
                $suLastName = $_POST['suLastName'];
                $suEmail = $_POST['suEmail'];
                $suPassword = $_POST['suPassword'];
                $suDisplayName = $_POST['suDisplayName'];
                //$sql = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,email,password,displayName)Values('{$suFirstName}','{$suLastName}','{$suEmail}','{$suPassword}','{$suDisplayName}')");
                $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,email,password,displayName)Values('{$suFirstName}','{$suLastName}','{$suEmail}','{$suPassword}','{$suDisplayName}')");
                if($sql){
                    header('Location: emailSent.php');
                }else{
                    $errors[] = "Failed to insert.";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['logIn'])){
        $liEmail = $_POST['liEmail'];
        $liPassword = $_POST['liPassword'];

        //$result = $connection->query("select * from users where email = '$liEmail' AND password = '$liPassword'");
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from users where email = '$liEmail' AND password = '$liPassword'");
        if($result){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['userID'];
        }
    }
?>

<?php 
    if(!empty($errors)){
        foreach ($errors as $value) {
            echo "<span style='color:red;'>".$value."</span><br>";
        }
    }
?>

<button type="button" id="showSignup">Show Sign-up</button><br><br>

<!-- Sign Up Box -->
<div class="sign-up-box" id="home-sign-up-box">
    <img src="images/icons/x-close.png" class="x-close" id="home-sign-up-close" src="x-close">
    <font class="subheader-bold font-raleway" id="box-sign-up-text">Sign Up</font>
    <form method="post" action="" id="home-sign-up-form">
        <input type="text" name="suFirstName" placeholder="First Name" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-first-name-text-input" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['suFirstName'])){echo $_POST['suFirstName'];}?>">
        <input type="text" name="suLastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-last-name-text-input" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['suLastName'])){echo $_POST['suLastName'];}?>">
        <input type="text" name="suEmail" placeholder="Email" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-email-text-input"value="<?php if(isset($_POST['suEmail'])){echo $_POST['suEmail'];}?>">
        <input type="password" name="suPassword" placeholder="Password" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-password-text-input">
        <input type="password" name="suConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-confirm-password-text-input">
        <input type="text" name="suDisplayName" placeholder="Display Name (you can change this later)" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-display-name-text-input" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['suDisplayName'])){echo $_POST['suDisplayName'];}?>">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="suRememberMe" value="yes" id="sign-up-remember-me-checkbox"><font id="sign-up-remember-me-text">Remember me</font></label>
        <input name="signUp" type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="sign-up-submit">
    </form>
    <font class="text-minor" id="agree-tos-pp-text">By signing up, you agree to our <a href="#">terms of service</a> and <br><a href="#">privacy policy</a>.</font>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        <?php if(isset($_POST['signUp']) && count($errors)>0){ ?>
            $('#home-sign-up-box').show();
        <?php }elseif(isset($_POST['signUp']) && count($errors)==0){ ?>
            //$('#home-sign-up-box').hide();
        <?php }else{?>
            //$('#home-sign-up-box').show();
        <?php }?>


        $("#showSignup").click(function(){
            $('#home-sign-up-box').toggle();
            visible_check();
        });
        visible_check();
    });

    function visible_check(){
        var isVisible = $( "#home-sign-up-box" ).is( ":visible" );
        if(isVisible){
            $("#showSignup").html("Hide Sign-up");
        }else{
            $("#showSignup").html("Show Sign-up");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! However when I use this the button I use to open the div doesn't work

Comment: Hi, It still does not work. When I remove `$(document).ready(function(){
        <?php if(isset($_POST['signUp']) && count($errors)>0){ ?>
            $('#home-sign-up-box').show();
        <?php }elseif(isset($_POST['signUp']) && count($errors)==0){ ?>
            //$('#home-sign-up-box').hide();
        <?php }else{?>
            //$('#home-sign-up-box').show();
        <?php }?>
});` however, it does work.